# initializing terragrunt using tofu fails to install the github provider authentication signature from unknown issuer

Tags: terraform, opentofu

Terragrunt init --upgrade

```
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing registry.opentofu.org/integrations/github v5.45.0:
│ authentication signature from unknown issuer
╵
seems to install it fine earlier on then fails. same repo
- Finding integrations/github versions matching "~> 5.45.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/helm versions matching ">= 2.7.0"...
- Finding latest version of registry.opentofu.org/hashicorp/helm...
- Finding latest version of registry.opentofu.org/integrations/github...
- Finding hashicorp/azuread versions matching ">= 2.43.0"...
- Finding latest version of registry.opentofu.org/hashicorp/random...
- Installing hashicorp/kubernetes v2.25.2...
- Installed hashicorp/kubernetes v2.25.2 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/helm v2.12.1...
- Installed hashicorp/helm v2.12.1 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing registry.opentofu.org/integrations/github v5.45.0...
- Installing integrations/github v5.45.0...
- Installed integrations/github v5.45.0 (signed by a HashiCorp partner, key ID 38027F80D7FD5FB2)
```

I've tried multiple versions of github integration and tofu(alpha and beta). Don't know what else to do. this is powershell on win10, using terraform, terragrunt and opentofu